# 3 Quick Questions on CV for training and testing data

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am trying to check if the model is over-fitting/under-fitting. I am using Decision trees. I am doing this using two approaches. **I have three questions:**

1. Which one of these two approaches is correct? Or both are correct?
2. How can I produce reproducible results in Approach 2? The code is not giving me reproducible results although I have `random_state=0` for the KFold.
3. Why am I getting different mean r^2 when comparing both approaches? Do I have a coding mistake in Approach 2?

   ```
    X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]

    new_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=9,
                                          min_samples_split=10,random_state=0)
   ```

**#Approach 1**

```
 tr_scores = []
    test_scores = []

for i in range(5):

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_normalized, y_for_normalized, test_size=0.1)
    clf=new_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    tr_sc = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    ts_sc = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    print ("Train score:", tr_sc) # from documentation .score returns r^2
    print ("Test score:", ts_sc)   # from documentation .score returns r^2
    tr_scores.append(tr_sc)
    test_scores.append(ts_sc)
    
print ("The Mean for Train scores is:",(np.mean(tr_scores)))
    
print ("The Mean for Test scores is:",(np.mean(test_scores)))

Train score: 0.8820641867211575
Test score: 0.4279649467398362
Train score: 0.8839084329275343
Test score: 0.7091393399433875
Train score: 0.8843199505270087
Test score: 0.3154296300279257
Train score: 0.907111269743484
Test score: 0.2681200352213015
Train score: 0.9215115563140909
Test score: 0.6260862924275742
The Mean for Train scores is: 0.895783079246655
The Mean for Test scores is: 0.46934804887200504
```

**#Approach 2**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

scorer = SCORERS['r2']

cv = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0,shuffle=True))
train_scores, test_scores = [], []

for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    
    O=new_model.fit(X_normalized.iloc[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
    tr_2 = O.score(X_train, y_train)
    ts_2 = O.score(X_test, y_test)
    print ("Train score:", tr_2) # from documentation .score returns r^2
    print ("Test score:", ts_2)   # from documentation .score returns r^2
    
    train_scores.append(tr_2)
    test_scores.append(ts_2)

    
    
print ("The Mean for Train scores is:",(np.mean(train_scores)))
    
print ("The Mean for Test scores is:",(np.mean(test_scores)))

Train score: 0.8917415272016388
Test score: -2.1141028447950108
Train score: 0.7691262820051474
Test score: 0.6805248231150614
Train score: 0.5482431713925354
Test score: 0.17706078877649534
Train score: 0.7742875457423143
Test score: 0.7732901880992943
Train score: 0.713243881823298
Test score: 0.5761896613464573
The Mean for Train scores is: 0.7393284816329867
The Mean for Test scores is: 0.01859252330845953
```

Comment: I notice that you've deleted most of the question. This makes the content hard to understand, because the description of the differences between Approach 1 and Approach 2 are missing. Additionally, making this kind of revision after getting an answer makes the answer you've received appear unrelated to the question, even though it's responsive to the original post. I've rolled back the edit.

Comment: Thank you !!!!! I wasn’t able to do that. Any chance you can advise on my code error?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382841/error-doing-cv-for-training-and-testing-datasets/73383154?noredirect=1#comment129594450_73383154

Answer (score 1):

> Which one of these two approaches is correct? Or both are correct?

Approach number 2 is just cross validation, which is the preferred method for estimating out of sample performance.  The problem with approach 1 is that there is no assurance that all data in your training set will be held out and predicted on.

> How can I produce reproducible results in Approach 2?

Without access to you data and code, it is hard to say.  Here is a reproducible example which yields the same CV score each time it is run

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000, n_features=10, random_state=0)

# Note here I am passing a random_state argument to DecisionTreeRegressor.
# This will ensure the model remains the same from run to run
model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3, max_features=3, random_state=0)
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)

for _ in range(10):
    score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=cv, scoring='r2')
    print(score.mean())
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
0.41200000000000003
```

> Why am I getting different mean r^2 when comparing both approaches? Do I have a coding mistake in Approach 2?

Again, hard to say without the data.  Ensure that the hold out sets are the same size in each approach. In the first, you hold out 10% of the data, in the latter you hold out 20% (4 for training, 1 for testing).  Again, there may be an issue with not testing on all the data in the first approach.  If you would like more help, please post a minimal reproducible example dataset we can work with.

Comment: @Z47 I am available for private consulting for a nominal fee.  You're best to keep this on this forum for other people to benefit from.

Comment: I understand thank you and thank you for always providing informative answers.

Comment: @dipetkov I am sorry, my code was wrong and I am still figuring it out.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585772/error-doing-cv-for-traning-and-testing-datasets

Comment: @Z47 Please either delete this post or return the original context to the question,